# Visio stencil isn't showing properly

Tags: microsoft-visio

I downloaded [these](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36448) stencils for Microsoft Visio 2013 and opened them in the application. For each icon I drag into the page (see image one), it shows up blue (see image two). What am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think these are older shapes and weren't designed with theming in mind.  Try applying 'No Theme' from the gallery on the Design ribbon tab, or, on a shape by shape (or Selection) basis, you can select the shape and click the 'Remove Theme' option on the Quick Styles drop-down (on the Home tab).

Comment: Thanks. I did solve this over the following days and forgot to update. Starting with no theme works great.